# CSS styling for multiple divs and a media player

Tags: html, positioning, css-float, padding

I'm trying to style the following page:

http://www.davedaranjo.com/media.html

The problem I'm having is that I really need to center div left and div right on the page with the header. Can someone suggest an style or attribute that would just move the whole section under the header over to the middle of the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points.

1. You [shouldn't use tables for layouts](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html).
2. The music player is not part of your div#right, the JavaScript inserts it after your <div align="center">.

But, if you want to stick with the site as it is, the following will center all of the components for you:

```
<body style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Note, the CSS should be stored in a [file external to your HTML](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html). If you use a separate file add the following to it:

```
body { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make it so that the div under the body that's aligned to center also contains the div with the class `ttw-music-player`.

Side note: I'm not sure if you know this, but the ttw-music-player div is the actual content on the right.  The div that has the id of 'right' doesn't have anything in it, since the javascript in there doesn't actually put anything on the page.

Once you do that, you can set the centering div so it has a specific width and also set it to `margin: auto;` instead of `align: center;`.  This will wrangle the header and the left and right content divs into the container.  After that, specify fixed widths on the left and right divs so that they take up an equal amount of space that adds up to exactly the width of the container div.  Then float one left and the other right.  You may need to play with the `width`, `padding`, and/or `margin` to get everything pixel-perfect.

Also, I'd suggest not using tables for anything except actual tables of data, and use CSS files in the `<head>` for all your styling.  Generally, you should stay away from inline styles that occur inside the html file itself, and just use JavaScript to add or remove CSS classes on elements, triggering inline styles from your JavaScript only if absolutely necessary.  It's much easier to maintain this way.

Comment: As John Keyes said, the JavaScript must be inserting the music player div after the body.  If you give the `<div align="right">` an id, `<div id="right">` for example, set the float to right with the CSS `#right { float: right; }` and change the text inside the $() from 'body' to 'container', it may just work.

Comment: That last part should be change from 'body' to '#right' .. StackOverflow doesn't let me edit comments after 5 mins.. -_-